# Google speech API developer error

Tags: python, api, cloud, speech

I had written code (basically the same as the python code under synchronous [here](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/sync-recognizecode)) before to transcribe a 10s wav file i made. Just today it stopped working and i get this error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ishan/Google_Cloudspeech_on_pepper/cloudspeechtest.py", line 35, in <module>
    response = client.recognize(config, audio)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/gapic/speech/v1/speech_client.py", line 201, in recognize
    return self._recognize(request, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/gax/api_callable.py", line 452, in inner
    return api_caller(api_call, this_settings, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/gax/api_callable.py", line 438, in base_caller
    return api_call(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/gax/api_callable.py", line 376, in inner
    return a_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/gax/retry.py", line 127, in inner
    ' classified as transient', exception)
google.gax.errors.RetryError: RetryError(Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient, caused by <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED, Quota exceeded.)>)`

Here is the code:

```
import io
from os import path

# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import speech
# from google.cloud import datastore #dont need this
from google.cloud.speech import enums
from google.cloud.speech import types

#client = datastore.Client()

GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = path.join(
    path.dirname(__file__),
    'ishan_sr.json')

# Instantiates a client
client = speech.SpeechClient()

# The name of the audio file to transcribe
file_name = path.join(
    path.dirname(__file__),
    'Fish.wav')

# Loads the audio into memory
with io.open(file_name, 'rb') as audio_file:
    content = audio_file.read()
    audio = types.RecognitionAudio(content=content)

config = types.RecognitionConfig(
    encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
    sample_rate_hertz=44100,
    language_code='en-US')

# Detects speech in the audio file
response = client.recognize(config, audio)

for result in response.results:
    print('Transcript: {}'.format(result.alternatives[0].transcript))
```

I haven't sent a request in a few weeks and my usage in my Google cloud dashboard shows my quota is not used. the code also stopped working on another account that I have so I think it is an error on Google's side or I need to update something?